# Storing Query Results in Class

Tags: python, oop

New to leveraging oop in python, but want to see if this is possible.

I am using the results of a SQL query to feed a process and want to store the data as variables for use in methods throughout the class. I have an ID that i pass when creating an instance of the class that is used to narrow the results to a single row. I want to avoid running the sql query each time i need to grab a variable, and instead, run it once and store the results in a variable for use throughout the class.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: It sounds like you want the query run when you create the instance, that is, in its `__init__` method. What have you tried, and what issues are you having? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. We're happy to help you figure out a problem you're having with your code, but we're not going to write it for you from scratch. Try something and ask us about the issues you get if it doesn't work!

Comment: @blckknght my current __init__ method just establishes passed through variables. 

What i'm currently doing is below (with server details removed)

'application_server= pyodbc.connect(connection script) '
I've then been attempting to use a method to do the sql run 
'def dataset_info(self): 
     qry_to_run = '''select * from set where set_id = ?''' 
     dataset_info = pandas.read_sql_query(junction_qry, self.application_server, params=[self.datasetid])' 
Essentially trying to return the dataframe. BUT! If i hear you right, i can establish this in the init function?

Comment: You can't usefully add code in a comment, edit that into the question!